# OpenGl does not render Mesh

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have tried to abtract my OpenGl code into classes, which has worked fine so far. It would always render until I recently build a Game class which is a derived class of the Window2 class (which I have also only recently created).
I am pretty sure that the bug is not to be found in the Mesh, Shader, PointLight or the Material class (as they have worked properly in the past).
The window does appear and has the correct background color. The render function is also called in the game loop so I am not sure what the problem is. Here is the code...

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H


#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "GameBlock.h"
#include "blocks/NormalGameBlock.h"
#include <PointLight.h>
#include <Window2.h>
#include <memory>
#include <Renderer.h>
#include <Mesh.h>
#include <Shader.h>
#include <Material.h>
#include <Utils.h>

class Game : private Window2 {
private:


    Mesh* mesh;
    Shader* shader;
    Material* material;

    PointLight* pointLight;

    glm::mat4 projection;
    glm::vec3 viewPosition;
    glm::mat4 view;

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void initialize();
    void start();
    void stop();

    // override the functions provided by base class Window2
    void input(Keys k) override;
    void update() override;
    void render() override;
};

#endif
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
    :
    Window2((int)(1080 * 0.7f), (int)(1920 * 0.7f), "Game", false)
{
    PRINT_FUNC;
    pointLight = new PointLight
    (
        glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * 0.0f,
        glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * 0.3f,
        glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * 1.0f,
        1.0f,
        0.01f,
        0.01f
    );

    material = new Material
    (
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * 1.0f,
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * 1.0f,
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) * 1.0f,
        1.0f,
        256.0f,
        1.0f
    );
}

Game::~Game() {
    PRINT_FUNC;
    delete mesh;
    delete shader;
    delete material;
    delete pointLight;
}

void Game::initialize() {
    PRINT_FUNC;

    Window2::intitialize2();

    mesh = new Mesh(Mesh::loadVertices("assets/box2.obj", false));
    shader = new Shader("shaders/vertex_shader copy.glsl", "shaders/fragment_shader copy.glsl");

    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(35.0f), 9.0f / 16.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    viewPosition = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
    view = glm::lookAt(
        viewPosition,          // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),    // and looks at the origin
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)     // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

}

void Game::start() {
    run();
}

void Game::stop() {
    close();
}

void Game::input(Keys k) {

}

void Game::update() {

}

void Game::render() {

    shader->activate();
    shader->setMat4("P", projection);
    shader->setMat4("V", view);
    shader->setVec3("viewPos", viewPosition);

    Renderer::render(mesh, shader, material, pointLight);

}
```

**Window2.h**

```
#ifndef WINDOW_2_H
#define WINDOW_2_H

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h> // include GLEW and new version of GL on Windows
#include <glfw3.h>   // GLFW helper library

#include <iostream>

struct Keys {
    bool W, A, S, D;
    bool Left, Right, Up, Down;
    bool N0, N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9;
    bool Space, Esc;
    bool Shift;
};

class Window2 {
private:

    GLFWmonitor* m_monitor;

    unsigned int m_width;
    unsigned int m_height;
    int m_posX;
    int m_posY;
    const char* m_title;
    const bool m_fullscreen;

    float aspectRatio;

public:

    GLFWwindow* m_window;

    Window2(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const char* title, const bool fullscreen);
    ~Window2();

    void intitialize2();

    void run();

    void close();

    // override functions
    virtual void input(Keys k);

    virtual void update();

    virtual void render();

    void setResizeCallback(void(*ptr)(GLFWwindow*, int, int));

    void setSize(int width, int height);

    float getAspectRatio();

    void makeCurrent() const;

    // clear window
    void clear(float r, float g, float b);

    // swap
    void swap();

    // poll events
    void poll();

    // get time in milliseconds
    static unsigned int getTimeMS();
};

#endif
```

**Window2.cpp**

```
#include "Window2.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Utils.h>

Window2::Window2
(
    unsigned int width,
    unsigned int height,
    const char* title,
    const bool fullscreen
)
    :
    m_width(width),
    m_height(height),
    m_title(title),
    m_fullscreen(fullscreen)
{
    PRINT_FUNC;
}

Window2::~Window2() {
    PRINT_FUNC;
    glfwDestroyWindow(m_window);
}

void Window2::intitialize2() {
    PRINT_FUNC;
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return;
    }

    const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    m_width = m_fullscreen ? mode->width : m_width;
    m_height = m_fullscreen ? mode->height : m_height;
    aspectRatio = (float)m_width / (float)m_height;
    m_window = glfwCreateWindow(m_width, m_height, m_title, m_fullscreen ? glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : NULL, NULL);
    if (!m_window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open Window2 with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    //setSize(m_width, m_height);

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n\n", version);
}

void Window2::run() {

    PRINT_FUNC;

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    unsigned int previous = getTimeMS();
    unsigned int lag = 0;
    const unsigned int msPerUpdate = 1000 / 60;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_window)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1);

        unsigned int current = getTimeMS();
        unsigned int elapsed = current - previous;
        previous = current;
        lag += elapsed;

        const Keys k{
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS,

            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS,

            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_0) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_1) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_2) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_3) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_4) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_5) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_6) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_7) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_8) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_9) == GLFW_PRESS,

            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS,
            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS,

            glfwGetKey(m_window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT) == GLFW_PRESS
        };

        //input
        input(k);

        while (lag >= msPerUpdate)
        {
            // update
            update();

            lag -= msPerUpdate;
        }

        // render
        render();

        glfwSwapBuffers(m_window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void Window2::input(Keys k) {

}

void Window2::update() {

}

void Window2::render() {

}

void Window2::close() {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(m_window, GLFW_TRUE);
}

void Window2::setSize(int width, int height) {
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    aspectRatio = (float)m_width / (float)m_height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void Window2::setResizeCallback(void(*ptr)(GLFWwindow*, int, int)) {
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_window, ptr);
}

void Window2::makeCurrent() const {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
}

float Window2::getAspectRatio() {
    return aspectRatio;
}

unsigned int Window2::getTimeMS() {
    std::chrono::milliseconds mt = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    return mt.count();
}
```

**This is how the class is created in Main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  Game game;
  game.initialize();
  game.start();

  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I would expect you to set the version of OpenGL, after `glfwInit()`. For instance set it to version **3.3**, I use 4.6:

```cpp
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

The general rendering routine looks like this. Check where and if glUseProgram called somewhere, and if it is called:

```
    glUseProgram(progId);
    glBindVertexArray(vao); //vertex array object here, (not vertex buffer object)
    glDrawXXX(GL_XXX, args); //for instance glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
```

I suppose shaders are compiled and program is linked successfully. So far is hard to guess from provided code. Other guesses might be missing some transformation, or missing any bind before drawing. The MVP transformation might send the object outside the window just by a small mistake. Transforming GL routines to OOP should be done in small steps. The way it is implemented really shows the level of understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @armagedescu. It work fine without providing the version before. I am also confident that the problem does not lie in the order of events (like binding buffers...) as I have looked at that using the PRINT_FUNC macro in the code.